# Appian field validation erases field value

Tags: validation, appian

I have an appian form with fields which should accept only numbers.
There is a **submit** button and a **cancel** button.

However, i cannot make the buttons restore original values on failed validations.

When a **submit** button is clicked, if the values are not numbers, error message should appear and the original value should be restored.
When the **cancel** button is clicked, original value should be restored.

This is the validation i am using on that field :

```
validation: if(typeof(local!myLocalObject.numField1)<>1,
  "This field must have a numeric value",
  null
)
```

**cancel** button contains the following code :

```
saveInto: {
  ...
  a!save(local!myLocalObject.numField1, ri!retrievedFromDB.numField1),
  ...
}
```

**save** button contains the following code :

```
saveInto: {
  ...
  if(typeof(local!myLocalObject.numField1)<>1,
    a!save(local!myLocalObject.numField1, ri!retrievedFromDB.numField1),
    null
  )
  ...
}
```

So this is what happens :

I have the field with a numeric value, and i make it editable :

[image: I have the field with a numeric value]

When i change the value to text and click submit,

[image]

It should restore the original value and display the error :

[image]

But what happens, is that the field becomes blank, with no value at all, and no error message. It can then be saved to DB as **null** which is a mistake.
[image]

(Note, this also happens when i just click out of that field)

The field type is **textField** and its **value** and **saveinto** are both set to **local!myLocalObject.numField1**

I have tried to use **integerField** instead, but then when I cancell out of saving, it fails to restore the original value :

[image]

and i have to reload the page to make the error message and the incorrect value go away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. When you do it like this :

```
local!myLocalObject: 'type:...'(
    ...
    numericField1 : ri!ruleInput.numericField1,
    ...
)

textField: {
    label: "Numeric Field 1",
    value: local!myLocalObject.numericField1,
    saveInto: local!myLocalObject.numericField1
    ...
}
```

**myLocalObject.numericField1** is predefined to have a numeric value because **myLocalObject** is of the same type as the rule input. So the text field will parse automatically anything you type there.

This is the workaround i am using :

```
local!myNumericField1 : ri!ruleInput.numericField1,


textField: {
    label: "Numeric Field 1",
    value: local!myNumericField1,
    saveInto: local!myNumericField1
    ...
}
```